# How do I unlock the bootloader on my Sony Ericsson Xperia mini pro?

Tags: rooting, fastboot, bootloader, sony-xperia-mini-pro

I own a "**Sony Ericsson Xperia Mini Pro**" (model number **SK17i**) running **Android 2.3.3** (**Kernel 2.6.32.8-perf**, build number **4.0.A.2.335**). It's **branded by Orange Austria**. **I'm looking for a way to root it**, but all I could find doesn't help. I've read the [xda-devel thread on rooting my phone](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1216783) and followed the [xda-guide](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=16659481&postcount=33) mentioned there. That doesn't work as planned.

The problem seems to be the branding. Fastboot won't recognize my device since I'm not able to unlock the boot loader. The phone just goes to normal charging mode, when I press [volume down] while connecting the USB cable (volume up will do nothing).

Hence my question: **Is there a workaround to unlock the bootloader or an alternative way of rooting?** I looked and found a method of [unlocking the bootloader using the device's testpoint](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1285285). According to one post there, the author succeded in unlocking his orange branded phone. For me the method described there results in a frozen s1tool and no effect on my Xperia.

Thanks for your help.

**Edit:**
Now it seems that nothing can be done if `dial *#*#7378423#*#* -> "Service Info" -> "Configuration" -> "Bootloader unlock allowed:"` says `No`.

Answer (score 4):

Because your phone is branded by Orange Austria, the SIM card is likely locked.  SonyEricsson states: ... you can’t unlock the boot loader if you have a SIM lock protected phone

http://unlockbootloader.sonyericsson.com/which-phones#13182586887331&if_height=1139

Comment: I don't get it, why some people say phones cannot be unlocked. Some other people (in the other threads) are saying that if you give them a call and say that you are going overseas and need your phone unlocked, they would unlock it for us? So doesn't that mean that phones *can* be unlocked?